# send textbox input on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an input and a button

```
<input type="text" name="search_tags" id="search_tags" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control"  >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="searchTags()">Search</button>
```

How do I pass the text present in the input textbox to the searchTags() function after button ng-click?

Comment: Try to add ng-model attribut to the input tag : `<input type="text" name="search_tags" id="search_tags" ng-model="myText" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control"  >`. Then you can access myText value in the searchTags() method using the $scope service : `$scope.myText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive with the `input` control, then pass that to `ngClick` of button.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText">
<button type="submit"  ng-click="searchTags(myText)">Search</button>
```

The property `myText` will be accessible in `$scope`

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a `ng-model` for your input field like that:

```
<input ng-model="myScopeVariable" type="text" name="search_tags" id="search_tags" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control" >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="searchTags(myScopeVariable)">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using angularJs. So you can give `ng-model` to the input so that you can access the value through it.

One way to access is

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text_content" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="searchTags(text_content)">Search</button>
```

otherwise, you can just access the value in controller with out passing in the function.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text_content" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="searchTags()">Search</button>
```

You can access the value in controller by `$scope.text_content`

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-model directive to bind data from the model to the view on HTML controls (input, select, textarea)

The ng-model directive provides a two-way binding between the model and the view.

```
<input ng-model="search_tag" type="text" name="search_tags" id="search_tags" placeholder="Search by Tags" class="form-control"  >
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="searchTags(search_tag)">Search</button>
```